# How can I set page specific user view access by user role?

Tags: 7, users

I need to be able to restrict access to specific pages based on user role, I heard that nodeaccess could do that, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do that with it, can you set page specific role access with nodeaccess? if not is there a module that can do that?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can install [nodeaccess](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeaccess) module and then configure it. It works for specific pages to restrict based on user access.

Comment: I have nodeaccess installed, and I see how I can restrict access to specific pages by user, but I want to be able to restrict access to specific pages by user role

Comment: Nodeaccess does control node access based on user Roles.  Do you see all the Roles listed in a table with checkboxes on the Grant tab?